# Can't change the tooltip y formatter in Apexcharts

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

I'm trying to do something that should be pretty trivial. I have a simple formatter method to change a number into a currency value. It works because you can see that the y axis values have been formatted to values like "$8,000". However, the tooltip y values are not formatted (as you can see in the picture). The documentation says that they should be formatted using the y axis formatter, which clearly isn't happening.

[image]

Even if I try a custom formatter, it seems to do nothing:

```
tooltip: {
  shared: false,
  intersect: true,
  x: {
    show: true,
  },
  y: {
    formatter: (y: any) => {
      return '$' + y;
    },
  },
},
```

The strange thing is that when I `console.log(...)` inside of that custom formatter, it prints once or twice, and only the Maximum value (e.g. 7380.69999999999) but not all five of the values like I would expect.

Relatedly, I can't get the tooltip x header to show. I'm [setting it to true](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/tooltip/#) but it doesn't appear.

I'm using vue but I don't think that matters. Almost every other Apexchart option seems to work except for this one.

Answer (score 2):

Going through a bit in the code of [apexcharts.js](https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/blob/67efa47e9c652a9859eb9fadfc7d990846408d9b/src/modules/settings/Defaults.js), I found this solution:

```js
tooltip: {
    shared: false,
    intersect: true,
    custom: function({ seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
      const minimum = w.globals.seriesCandleO[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]
      const q1 = w.globals.seriesCandleH[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]
      const median = w.globals.seriesCandleM[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]
      const q3 = w.globals.seriesCandleL[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]
      const maximum = w.globals.seriesCandleC[seriesIndex][dataPointIndex]

      return `<div class="apexcharts-tooltip-box apexcharts-tooltip-boxPlot">
        <div>Minimum: <span class="value">\$${minimum}</span></div>
        <div>Q1: <span class="value">\$${q1}</span></div>
        <div>Median: <span class="value">\$${median}</span></div>
        <div>Q3: <span class="value">\$${q3}</span></div>
        <div>Maximum: <span class="value">\$${maximum}</span></div>
      </div>`
    }
  }
```

Resulting in the following: 
[image: tooltip]

Demo in [codi.link](https://codi.link/PGRpdiBpZD0iY2hhcnQiPjwvZGl2Pg0KDQo8c2NyaXB0IHNyYz0iaHR0cHM6Ly9jZG4uanNkZWxpdnIubmV0L25wbS9hcGV4Y2hhcnRzIj48L3NjcmlwdD4=%7C%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)

Comment: Thank you. It's a shame that we have to resort to custom code in order to make this work. I can't tell if it's a bug in apexcharts or if I'm just doing something blatantly wrong.

Comment: @kevlar Instead of an error, I see it more like: "I give you the tools, find out how to implement them for your use case" 

Comment: lol I agree in general, except in theory this functionality is supported.

Comment: @kevlar It also gives the feeling that the documentation is complete, but at the same time it is not